# How to display the elements starting from left?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to web programming and I have a following problem:

I wish to display the data *starting* from left. That is, consider this as a screen:

```
Screen                                                                       2332
```

and if `2332` increase to `2339900` then my screen should be:

```
Screen                                                                    2339900
```

I have code like this:

```
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Units entered</b></td>
            <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Consumption charges</b></td>
            <td>23232323</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Fixed charges</b></td>
            <td>323232323</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Net Amount</b></td>
            <td>3223232332</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I tried adding `style="float: left;"` to my `td` tag but that doesn't help me.

How I can achieve this.

Note: I'm using bootstrap, if by chance bootstrap supports it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap has the utility class 'text-right' built into the latest version so you can just apply that class to your TD. My jsfiddle shows what the utility class does but you wouldn;t have to actually include the css as Bootstrap already has it. You just need to use the class name.

Details here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#typography

Here's how you would do that: http://jsfiddle.net/mpPP6/

```
 .text-right {
     text-align: right;
 }

<table width="100%">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Units entered</b></td>
            <td class="text-right">123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Consumption charges</b></td>
            <td class="text-right">23232323</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Fixed charges</b></td>
            <td class="text-right">323232323</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Net Amount</b></td>
            <td class="text-right">3223232332</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

P.S I'd recommend you swap your 'b' tags for 'strong' tags or even add a class to those TDs you want to have strong text and set it through the css with:

```
.myclass {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

To override Bootstrap's .table class which aligns everything to the left within table cells simply add this line to your custom css file.

```
.table .text-right {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: thanks. But when I add `class="table"` to my `table` tag. The alignment doesn't work.

Comment: @sriram - I've updated my answer to show you how to override that. Look at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/nhf9J/)

Just use the `align="right"` like following...

```
<table class="table" width="100%">
            <tbody>
            <tr >
                <td><b>Units entered</b></td>
                <td align="right">123</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Consumption charges</b></td>
                <td align="right">23232323</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Fixed charges</b></td>
                <td align="right">323232323</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Net Amount</b></td>
                <td align="right">3223232332</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well there are two things you can do (from the top of my head, at least!):

1. Use Bootstrap's scaffolding:

   ```
   <div class="span12">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="span3"><strong>Units entered</strong></span>
           <div class="span3 offset6">123</span>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. Style the table:

HTML:

```
    <tr>
        <td><b>Units entered</b></td>
        <td class="align-right">123</td>
    </tr>
```

CSS:

```
    .align-right { text-align:right; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<td align="left">
```

will left align the contents of the cell. Looking at your "Screen", the numbers are seem to be right aligned ?